# Proper line-ending for an open-source PHP project

Tags: windows, linux, macos, newlines

What is the proper line-ending preferences for an open-source web project? Obviously it includes source code of PHP, HTML, CSS and Javascript.

The source code is managing via Github now, and there are Windows (8 & 7), Linux (Ubuntu) and OSX developers inside the team, which means all the major operating systems.

P.S. We are using "Windows" CRLF line-ending, plus "UTF-8 without BOM" right now, without facing any problem, however I think it might be better to use "*nix/OSX" LF style. I heard some stories about the problems that caused by the additional "CR" on Linux or OS X.

Comment: Remember to _not_ put `?>` at the end of your PHP files.

Comment: @MichaelHampton yeah, I've seen that mainly on Zend and Yii frameworks, could you explain me why? thanks!

Comment: [PHP closing tag](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4410704/1068283)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

windows line ending will cause problems on Linux and some times on Mac too. I've seen some Mac files on linux which appear to have a `^M` at the end of each line.
So, you best choice is the Linux line ending...

Comment: yes, I have heard the same from others also! thanks!

Comment: Notepad itself does not recognize just \n, however I do think that is the widely accepted format. In my opinion it shouldn't matter - it's easy enough to convert between different formats.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, Programmer's notepad can handle *nix line endings, even if Notepad.exe can't. Also, Git can automatically convert line endings: see https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings